# Custom web hook listener

Tags: git, events, webhooks

I am new to the web hook concept.

We have a requirement where in I need to listen to a repository for `Git` commits, and then the payloads are sent across to some URL through a REST API.

I am thinking that it should be on the similar lines as Webhooks-GitHub API.

How can I customize that API to listen to any custom repo which is not Github hosted? is there a way?

Answer (score 0):

Git itself has its own hooks mechanism store inside your .git/hooks folder.

More info about hooks:
http://git-scm.com/book/be/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks
https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-hooks/

Comment: I see, so it seems that all the things needs to be handled via script? I mean, insert a script inside the 'hook' folder and then fire an rest call from there with the payload?